Default layout is not appearing in error.vue using Nuxt 3
What is happening?
I am creating a ~/error.vue file to display a custom error page.
I need the default layout to be applied as I want the design of the app to be as most uniform as possible.
Default layout is working on every page except on ~/error.vue file.
What have I tried?
I am using throw createError to go directly to my ~/error.vue and test it fast.
What I've tried is to wrap the template content with <NuxtLayout><NuxtLayout> but doing that, ~/error.vue is ignored and the user is never redirected. It doesn't even show an error, It just does nothing.

I've finally managed it to work.
What was wrong?
In my default.vue layout I had a estructure like this:
<template>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="main-layout pb-10">
            <CustomHeader />
            <main class="main-container">
                <NuxtPage />
            </main>
            <button @click="handleError">Test the error</button>
            <CustomFooter/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

And reading some logs from the browser console led me to try to change <NuxtPage /> to <slot /> as ~/error.vue is not a Nuxt page...
And it worked like a charm!

This is an expected behavior. The error page is used for fatal errors (any unhandled error on the server, or an error created with fatal: true on the client).
With a fatal error, only the error.vue page itself is guaranteed to be rendered properly. It's reasonable that it is without a layout.
The official documentation also states that rendering an error page is an entirely separate page load.
Ref: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#error-page

Ok... I understand, but on Nuxt 2 it was possible to use layouts on error.vue without any problem. Also, I found several guys who claim to have made the layouts work in error.vue with the  approach in Nuxt 3, that's why I asked what was happening.
